# Download .torrent file through php, Invalid Bencoding

Tags: php, file, header, torrent

I'm writing a custom php application that should allow downloading of torrent files.
Files are located on the server, and per user request,I serve the file the following way:

```
    if( file_exists( $torrent_file ) ) {
        header("Content-type: application/x-bittorrent");
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize( $torrent_file ));
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename( $torrent_file ).'"');

        readfile($torrent_file);
    }
```

But when I download and try to add the file to uTorrent I see the following error:

**Unable to load - Torrent is not valid Bencoding.**

I searched around to find a solution to this exact problem without any success.

Comment: Why don't use a library like PHPTracker (http://php-tracker.org/, example of what you want at https://bmain.net/d/2-create-torrent-files-with-php-and-phptracker)

Comment: Hi, the thing is that all torrent files are uploaded to the server by third party application, and all i have to do is to provide a way to download.

Answer (score 0):

After nearly a day of searching and googling, i found the problem.
It appeared that there was a trailing whitespace after the closing php tag, inside one of the included php files.
I removed the whitespace along with the closing tag and the problem was fixed.

Comment: curses! let me guess, was it the line ending `^M` character from a Windows-to-Unix copy-paste?

Comment: Yes! This was the exact problem :)